# Mod Rewrite to a non existent directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

my problem is, that if I rewrite my URL with following rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=meine-bar&filter=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^meine-bar/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?site=meine-bar&filter=$1 [L]
```

my index.php also recognizes the new URL and my dependencies are wrong.

For example.

Normally the link would be for example

`<link href="css/style.css" ... />`

now that I've rewritten the URL the index.php looks for the link in `meine-bar/css/style.css`

How can I tell the Mod Rewrite to just "virtually" redirect me to this non-existent folder? I dont want to be in the folder (because it doesn't exist), I just wan't the user to believe that this folder exists (the URL just has to look like it exists)

Comment: The only solution I see (not on the Mod_Rewrite side) is to check the REQUEST String in PHP and if it contains ../meine-bar/.. to prepand a "../" to each link. In this way it would correct each link but this doesn't seem to be a very clean solution.

Comment: What do you want your URL to look like? As in what the users will see?And then what is the exact URL it should rewrite too. I know you have an example but it makes it clearer for me to see what you want to accomplish.

Comment: My index.php?site=meine-bar is rewritten to /meine-bar
index.php?site=meine-bar&filter=sirup should be rewritten to meine-bar/sirup and it works, but as described in the question after this redirect all links are also using the new URL, but actually i just want the meine-bar/... displayed, but meine-bar is no real folder. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Ok made an answer. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Sorry, Then I guess I don't understand what you mean. Because my answer clearly fixes the problem you described and I gave an example sense most of my site is like that(non existent folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<link href="css/style.css" ... />
```

to this

```
<link href="/css/style.css" ... />
```

I believe it will still work as you need it to without meine-bar

The reason is you are using `relative` paths so it will pick up the directory the URL "thinks" it's in. To prevent that you need to use `absolute` paths. So by putting the `/` in front of the directory you are telling it to start at the webroot which is where you really want to be. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: My site uses non-existent folders. for example. http://www.mysite.com/groups/groupname well the directory groups does not exist and is a modrewite. If I link to something on the page like so <a href="menuitem.html">Item</a> The link appears as http://www.mysite.com/groups/menuitem.html which is wrong. However to fix that I change the link to <a href="/menuitem.html">Item</a> and the link appears as http://www.mysite.com/menuitem.html. So it does work in the **scenario** I thought you had.

Comment: The problem is, that each page is included dependent of the index.php?site parameter. So if i change it to /css/style.css it's wrong for each case besides if it's meine-bar/... (Also the path's in my css file are wrong, not only the links themself)
It would work if each page would be independent of the index.php

Comment: Yes, but I don't see why it wouldn't still work for your other pages. regardless of what you serve with index.php. style.css will and should always be located at http://yoursite.com/css/style.css right? Your style sheet never changes its location so using this /css/style.css should work regardless. If not I'd have to see more of the way you have index.php setup. I can't see how that wont work. I don't use relative paths anywhere on my site to prevent problems like these. Use the full URL or /. which is the same thing.

Comment: Using full URL's fixed it. Thanks for the hint! :)